# Need help for php and mysql code- getting data from another table for combined table

Tags: mysql

I am combining two tables using **UNION ALL** and then Randomized date using **ORDER BY RAND()**

First table:

```
OPDNo. | Dep  |   Ward   | Sex   | Name  |  BedNo
1        abc     abcmale     1     xx
5        abc     abcmale     1     yy
9        abc     abcmale     1     zz
```

Second table:

```
OPDNo. | Dep  |    Ward      | Sex   | Name  |  BedNo
8        abc     abcfemale     0      aa
6        abc     abcfemale     0      bb
7        abc     abcfemale     0      cc
```

My result after combining:

```
SELECT * from `firsttbl` UNION ALL SELECT * from `secondtble` ORDER BY RAND()
```

```
IPDno. | OPDNo. | Dep  |    Ward      | Sex   | Name  | BedNo
1         8        abc     abcfemale     0     aa
2         6        abc     abcfemale     0     bb
3         1        abc     abcmale       1     xx
4         7        abc     abcfemale     0     cc
5         5        abc     abcmale       1     yy
6         9        abc     abcmale       1     zz
```

Now my problem in which I need your help:

I have one more table **bed**

```
  Ward   |   Bed No | Status
abcmale        1        0
abcmale        2        0
abcmale        3        1
abcmale        4        0
abcmale        5        0
abcfemale      6        0
abcfemale      7        0
abcfemale      8        1
abcfemale      9        1
abcfemale      10       0
abcfemale      11       0
```

In my combined table I need to fill BedNo. from my bed table in which I can put only bed no with status 0 of particular ward.

My current code:

```
                   <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>IPD No.</th>
                      <th>OPD No.</th>                      
                      <th>Dep.</th>
                      <th>Ward</th>
                      <th>Bed</th>                      
                      <th>Sex</th>                      
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php
    
           $qipd="SELECT MAX(IPDNo) from ipd";
            $ripd = $conn->query($qipd);
         $ipdn=mysqli_fetch_array($ripd,MYSQLI_NUM);
            $ipdn= $ipdn[0]+1;
            $i=1;

          while($opd = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        ?>
    <form action="saveBulkipd.php" method="post">
         <?php
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td><input type="text" readonly value="'.$ipdn.'" name="'.$i.'ipdno"/></td>';   
                                  $ipdn++;
                            
         echo '<td><input type="text" readonly value="'.$opd['OPDNo'].'" name="'.$i.'opdno"/></td>';  
         
         echo '<td><input type="text" readonly value="'.$opd['PDep'].'" name="'.$i.'pdep"/></td>'; 
         echo '<td><input type="text" readonly value="'.$opd['PWard'].'" name="'.$i.'pward"/></td>';
        ?>
        <!--Bed  No. Logic-->
<td><input type="text" readonly value="'<?php
            
            $j=0;   
$bedq="SELECT `bed` from bed where ward='$opd[PWard]' and status=0";
$rbed = $conn->query($bedq);        
$bedno=array();
while($bedn=$rbed->fetch_assoc()) {
  
$bedno[]=$bedn['bed'];
}
            echo $bedno[$j];
            $j++;
            ?>'" name=""/></td>
        
        <!--Bed  No. Logic End-->
                    <?php
        
        echo '<td><input type="text" readonly value="'.$opd['PSex'].'" name="'.$i.'psex"/></td>';        
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
        
                              }
    
    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="bulksubmit" value="Save IPD Date" class="btn btn-default"/></td>
                    </tr>
     </form>
                  </tbody>
                  
                </table>
```

output I am getting

[image]

I am getting same bed no for each ward

Note: For simplicity I have removed many columns my issue is with bed no allotment only.

My desired Result set:

```
IPDno. | OPDNo. | Dep  |    Ward      | Sex   | Name  | BedNo
1         8        abc     abcfemale     0       aa        6
2         6        abc     abcfemale     0       bb        7
3         1        abc     abcmale       1       xx        1
4         7        abc     abcfemale     0       cc        10
5         5        abc     abcmale       1       yy        2
6         9        abc     abcmale       1       zz        4
```

As shown above table Bed no has been assigned using bed table in which status is 0 and of particular ward column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's best for questions like this if you show us your desired result set in the same sort of format you showed your tables. With respect, it's difficult to guess your requirement from the text of your question.   ALSO, this is a SQL question, not a php question. So, you could remove your entire php program and show just your SQL. Once you have worked out the SQL, then you can build it into your php.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have edited my question. And I think its a combined problem because I can do this for only one ward but Its problematic when doing this with more than one ward(Ward is a column name)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use PHP, try soething like next SQL

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM `firsttbl` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `secondtble` ORDER BY RAND()
) AS a
INNER JOIN `bed` ON `bed`.`BedNo` = `a`.`BedNo`
WHERE `bed`.`Status` = 1
```

Completely I can't reproduce, seems you wrote your DB tables with some mistakes

Comment: Thanks for reply but unfortunately I have tried above mentioned query and is not solving my issue. I have cut down some parts and mentioned it as mysql query issue in different case. If you can help me on that it will also work. My different tread link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63952976/enter-data-from-a-different-mysql-table