# Enter data from a different mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

My current query is:

```
INSERT INTO `ipdKayaChikitsaF`(`IPDNo`, `OPDNo`, `RegNo`, `PatientId`, `PDep`, `PWard`, `PBed`, `pSymptom`, `PDisease`, `PName`, `PMob`, `uid`, `PSex`, `PAge`, `PMStatus`, `PFname`, `PAddr`, `PDist`, `PState`, `OPDDate`, `dischargeStatus`, `admitOn`, `dischargeOn`, `CreatedOn`, `CreatedBy`) 
SELECT '1',OPDNo,RegNo,PatientId,PDep,'Kaya Chikitsa (Female)','1',pSymptom,'na',pname,PMob,uid,PSex, PAge,PMStatus,PFname,PAddr,PDist,PState,OPDDate,'0',OPDDate,'0000-00-00',OPDDate,'$user' 
from `opd` 
where OPDDate=STR_TO_DATE('$curDate','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND PDep='Kaya Chikitsa' AND PSex=0 GROUP BY `OPDNo`  
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $ipdKayaChikitsaF";
```

Above query is working properly:

Now kindly check select query mentioned in above query. Here I am selecting some values from table and some of them are hard codded. Now I want **PBed**  value to be filled from a different table in which a condition should be there.

My bed table has 3 columns like

```
  Ward                 |   Bed No | Status
Kaya Chikitsa (Female)       1        0
Kaya Chikitsa (Female)       2        0
Kaya Chikitsa (Female)       3        1
Kaya Chikitsa (Male)         4        0
Kaya Chikitsa (Male)         5        1
Kaya Chikitsa (Male)         6        0
```

I want to fill PBed with Bed No. from bed table and it should have condition of Ward='Kaya Chikitsa (Female)' and Status=0;

My result should be like this

Table `ipdKayaChikitsaF`

```
`IPDNo` | `OPDNo` | `RegNo` | `PatientId`  |   `PDep    |     `PWard`          | `PBed`  and so on...

1          267       1          12          Kaya Chikitsa  Kaya Chikitsa (Female)   1    and so on...
2          352       8          15          Kaya Chikitsa  Kaya Chikitsa (Female)   2    and so on...
and so on...
```

Kindly check above table her I want PBed column to be filled from bed table as conditions mentioned above.

Comment: What is the opd table ? What the connection between opd and "bed table" ? When yo uanswer this question you will have your answer...connection = column that connects this two tables or maybe a table that connects the opd table and "bed table"

Comment: OPD table has a department field and sex. It helps to find our ward. for example Dep name is Kaya Chikitsa and sex is female than Ward will be Kaya Chikitsa (Female). And bed table has ward name and list of vacant bed by status 0. So I need only bed from particular department with status 0 in it.

Comment: @VBoka  I am doing so but getting same value bed No. on each row of coulmn PBed of table ipdKayaChikitsaF

Comment: Provide some schema for opd table and bed table with some dummy data

Answer (score 0):

Use join in select query like. Note table opd must have a join field of pward for this query to work and I have assumed that the bed table name is bed_table

```
INSERT INTO `ipdKayaChikitsaF`(`IPDNo`, `OPDNo`, `RegNo`, `PatientId`, `PDep`, `PWard`, `PBed`, `pSymptom`, `PDisease`, `PName`, `PMob`, `uid`, `PSex`, `PAge`, `PMStatus`, `PFname`, `PAddr`, `PDist`, `PState`, `OPDDate`, `dischargeStatus`, `admitOn`, `dischargeOn`, `CreatedOn`, `CreatedBy`) 
SELECT '1',o.OPDNo,o.RegNo,o.PatientId,o.PDep,'Kaya Chikitsa (Female)','1',o.pSymptom,'na',o.pname,o.PMob,o.uid,o.PSex,o. PAge,o.PMStatus,o.PFname,o.PAddr,o.PDist,o.PState,o.OPDDate,'0',b.Ward, b.`Bed No`,o.OPDDate,'$user' 
from `opd` as o join bed_table b on b.Ward = o.pward
where OPDDate=STR_TO_DATE('$curDate','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND PDep='Kaya Chikitsa' AND PSex=0 GROUP BY `OPDNo`  
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $ipdKayaChikitsaF" and b.Ward = 'Kaya Chikitsa (Female)' and b.status = '0';
```

As you have no relation field in opd table you can use simple cartesian product to get that exact value of ward Kaya Chikitsa (Female) with status 0. Also, In the above query previously forgot to replace the static ward and bed no value in select query i.e **'Kaya Chikitsa (Female)','1'** with
b.Ward,b.`Bed No`. Therefore you were getting only value of "1" in bed no in the results.

```
    INSERT INTO `ipdKayaChikitsaF`(`IPDNo`, `OPDNo`, `RegNo`, `PatientId`, `PDep`, `PWard`, `PBed`, `pSymptom`, `PDisease`, `PName`, `PMob`, `uid`, `PSex`, `PAge`, `PMStatus`, `PFname`, `PAddr`, `PDist`, `PState`, `OPDDate`, `dischargeStatus`, `admitOn`, `dischargeOn`, `CreatedOn`, `CreatedBy`) 
    SELECT '1',o.OPDNo,o.RegNo,o.PatientId,o.PDep,b.Ward,b.`Bed No`,o.pSymptom,'na',o.pname,o.PMob,o.uid,o.PSex,o. PAge,o.PMStatus,o.PFname,o.PAddr,o.PDist,o.PState,o.OPDDate,'0',o.OPDDate,'0000-00-00',o.OPDDate,'$user' 
    from `opd` as o, (select Ward, `bed no` form bed_table where Status = 0 and Ward = 'Kaya Chikitsa (Female)' ) as b
    where OPDDate=STR_TO_DATE('$curDate','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND PDep='Kaya Chikitsa' AND PSex=0 GROUP BY `OPDNo`  
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $ipdKayaChikitsaF" and b.Ward = 'Kaya Chikitsa (Female)' and b.status = '0';
```

Comment: Opd table doesnt have pward column. And I tried this but bed showing only 1

Comment: then you can use simple Cartesian product  which i will show by changing the above post

Comment: Thanks for update. I have used your shared query but I am getting same value for each row for example: I am getting  2 for bed no. in each row.

Comment: The query does exactly that. If you want to assign different bed number to different opd patient there is no alternative to mainating relation of opd and bed number using foreign key.